# Creating a point buffer along a road network

Tags: qgis, buffer, network

I have a road network and have added points indicating fire hall locations.

How would i go about creating buffers on those points following the road line.

The result am i looking for would create a buffer from the fire hall to 5km away on all possible roads/paths.

I do have the full OSGeo suite. Currently using QGIS 2.0.1

Thanks

Comment: I think the terminology you are looking for are called service areas, or catchments areas, which are addressed in the question linked above.  If not, we can re-open your question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as familiar with QGIS as I would like to be so I'm not going to pretend to be an expert.

**But**....

I would start looking at [pgRouting](http://pgrouting.org/)

I know this can be done in ArcGIS and I'm sure theres a way in the open source environment.

---

Hope this helps.